# How to write unit tests for a grunt plugin that doesn't write files?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, plugins, gruntjs, grunt-plugins

I'm creating a grunt plugin which is responsible for finding URLs in a file and adding those URLs to a variable in the grunt file using

```
grunt.config.set('urls', urls);
```

All examples of unit test for Grunt plugins assume that the plugin is going to write a file and then compares that output to a test file with the 'expected' result.

Is there any way to test if my Grunt plugin has set a config variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
urlConfigTest: function(test) {
    test.expect(1);
    grunt.config.set('urls','http://foo.example.com');
    test.equal(grunt.config.get('urls'), 'http://foo.example.com', 'Should set foo to the grunt configuration.');
    test.done();
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I didn't realize the reference to grunt in the scaffolded test file actually held the current state.

Answer (score 1):

The Yo generator (*) for grunt-plugins basically is basically setting up tests like this:

1. Setup your `Gruntconfig.js` to run your plugin with a specific testconfig
2. Then configure a testrun by creating a test task: `grunt.registerTask('test', ['myPlugin', 'nodeunit']);`. This means that your plugin should have set the config values you like to test against.
3. Run the test like `test.equal(grunt.config.get('urls'), 'http://foo.example.com', 'Should ...');`

The Yo generator is maintained by Addy Osmani and Stephen Sawchuck, which might be counted as credible sources ;-)

(*) `npm install -g generator-gruntplugin`